nonlocal или func_name. в замыканиях
Вариант 1 и 2 для замыкания. Допустим ли в Python вариант 1 и есть ли в нем какие-либо недостатки или преимущества перед 2?
from functools import wraps

def repeated(count=3):
    repeated.call_count = 0               # ВАРИАНТ 1
    call_count = 0                        # ВАРИАНТ 2
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            repeated.call_count += 1      # 1
            nonlocal call_count           # 2
            call_count += 1               # 2
            # ...


Первый вариант загрязняет (немного) глобальное пространство имен. Второй - обычное замыкание. Что вы собираетесь делать с call_count?

Вариант 1 есть, но использовать его не нужно - не нужно добавлять какие-то "левые" поля не в свой класс/объект. К тому же, один и тот же счетчик будет использоваться для всех функций. Во втором вариант каждый отдельный декоратор будет считать только вызовы своей функции.

Первый вариант - это вообще не замыкание, считайте что это глобальная переменная.

Спасибо за разъяснения. В данном случае у меня декоратор просто как частный случай, приведен для примера. Периодически возникают такие ситуации просто для вложенных (служебных) функций.

Как я понял, вариант 1 ведет себя примерно как атрибут класса, но применительно к функции.  Соответственно будет, подобно атрибуту класса, один для всех вызовов функции repeated. При декорировании может быть пригоден только, если вдруг надо будет считать в один счетчик все вызовы всех функций, задекорированных repeated
